# Simple Annihilator Matrix Calculation in Econometrics

Tags: econometrics, matrix

While working on Davidson and McKinnon's *Econometric Theory and Methods*, I was encountered with

[image]

where $X = [X_1\  X_2]$, $M_X$ is the annihilator matrix for $X$, $M_1$ is for $X_1$ and so on.

In particular, I couldn't get the second equality.
How can we get $(M_1 - M_x) = M_1X_2(X_2^TM_1X_2)^{-1}X_2^TM_1$?

I tried but couldn't clearly understand how this result works. Can anybody help me? I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write out the definitions: $M_X=I-X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T$, $M_1=I-X_1(X_1^TX_1)^{-1}X_1^T$. Now simplify the r.h.s of your equality, first writing out $(X_2^T M_1X_2)^{-1}=X_2^{-1}M_1^{-1}{X_2^{T}}^{-1}$. Can you finish the problem now?

Comment: I am sorry to keep bothering with this seemingly extremely simple stuff.
Can we assume $X_2, M_1$ are invertible? If we assume so, I get that the LHS is


$$
I - X_1(X_1^TX_1)^{-1}X_1^T - (I  - X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T) = -X_1(X_1^TX_1)^{-1}X_1^T +X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T
$$

while the RHS becomes

$$
M_1X_2(X_2^TM_1X_2)^{-1}X_2^TM_1 = M_1X_2X_2^{-1}M_1^{-1}{X_2^T}^{-1}X_2^TM_1 = M_1.
$$

How can I connect the two?

Comment: What happens if you simplify $M_1-M_X$ using $X:=[X_1,X_2]$?

Comment: I tried but can't figure out what you meant. I guess, for any $X$, we have $(M_1 - M_X)X = M_1X - M_XX = M_1X$. Is it from here that we get $M_1-M_X = M_1$?

Comment: I think you got it. since $X$ is arbitrary, you've shown $(M_1-M_X)X=M_1X$ for any $X$, which gives the desired result.

Comment: If it helps, let $g(X):=(M_1-M_X)X-M_1X$. You've shown that $g(X)=0$.